# Reputation audit bug?

Tags: support, reputation-audit

I looked at the [reputation audit page](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation), and I saw something strange:

> rep this year (2013-01-01 - 2013-12-31): **2283**
>   total rep **2284** :)

I signed up this year, so actually I should have earned 2284, but it shows 2283 for 'rep this year'.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: Don't forget the 1 that you start with.

Comment: @Mysticial: Thank you! I think you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everybody starts with 1 rep. So it doesn't count towards what you have *gained*.